# How can I optimize this UserAgent parser for loop in C#?

Tags: string, optimization, c#-4.0, user-agent

I am writing a C# program to analyze the the number of browsers in the UserAgent column of a web server log. I wish to output the browser type, browser major version, and the number of hits.

How can I optimize this?

I am using regex to compare the UserAgent string with predefined strings to test for Firefox, Opera, etc. I then use regex to cancel out a possible mismatch. I then use a regex to obtain the major version. I use a struct to hold this information for each browser:

```
private struct Browser
{
    public int ID;
    public string name;
    public string regex_match;
    public string regex_not;
    public string regex_version;
    public int regex_group;
}
```

I then load the browser information and loop over all of the records for the UserAgent:

```
Browser[] browsers = new Browser[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    browsers[i].ID = i;
}
browsers[0].name = "Firefox";
browsers[1].name = "Opera";
browsers[2].name = "Chrome";
browsers[3].name = "Safari";
browsers[4].name = "Internet Explorer";
browsers[0].regex_match = "(?i)firefox/([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[1].regex_match = "(?i)opera/([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[2].regex_match = "(?i)chrome/([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[3].regex_match = "(?i)safari/([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[4].regex_match = "(?i)msie([+_ ]|)([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[0].regex_not = "(?i)flock";
browsers[1].regex_not = "";
browsers[2].regex_not = "";
browsers[3].regex_not = "(?i)android|arora|chrome|shiira";
browsers[4].regex_not = "(?i)webtv|omniweb|opera";
browsers[0].regex_version = "(?i)firefox/([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[1].regex_version = "(?i)opera/([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[2].regex_version = "(?i)chrome/([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[3].regex_version = "(?i)version/([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[4].regex_version = "(?i)msie([+_ ]|)([\\d\\.]*)";
browsers[0].regex_group = 1;
browsers[1].regex_group = 1;
browsers[2].regex_group = 1;
browsers[3].regex_group = 1;
browsers[4].regex_group = 2;
Dictionary<string, int> browser_counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 65000; i++)
{
    foreach (Browser b in browsers)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(csUserAgent[i], b.regex_match))
        {
            if (b.regex_not != "")
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(csUserAgent[i], b.regex_not))
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            string strBrowser = b.name;
            if (b.regex_version != "")
            {
                string strVersion = Regex.Match(csUserAgent[i], b.regex_version).Groups[b.regex_group].Value;
                int intPeriod = strVersion.IndexOf('.');
                if (intPeriod > 0)
                {
                    strBrowser += " " + strVersion.Substring(0, intPeriod);
                }
            }
            if (!browser_counts.ContainsKey(strBrowser))
            {
                browser_counts.Add(strBrowser, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                browser_counts[strBrowser]++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

- construct a hashtable or most-frequently matches user-agent and avoid matching the regexen.
- store compile new `Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled)` instead of just `pattern`
- combine the regexes into a single regex and take advantage of RegexOptions.Compiled and RegexOptions.CultureInvariantIgnoreCase
- instead of matching twice (once with `IsMatch` and once with `Matches`) match once (`Matches`) and check whether the MatchCollection is empty

This is only a starting point - I might come up with more ideas on reading the code :)

**Edit** One more:

- avoid parsing the version with another regex - only safari requires special treaetment according to your config. Try to 'catch' the version with the same regex as the browserid. (I'd simply make an exception for safari for now)

---

E.g. you could have a single static regex instance like this:

```
private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(
    "(?i)" 
    + "(?<browserid>(?:firefox/|opera/|chrome/|chrome/|safari/|msie[+_ ]?))"
    + "(?<version>[\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

You can conveniently access the proper subgroups by using `match.Groups["browserid"]` and `match.Groups["version"]`. This nearly eliminates all the use for your list of Browser structs.

The only thing it still caters for is the exclusion regex (regex_not). I suggest re-profiling with the single positive regex first, though and see whether there is still a performance problem left before frying smaller fish.

## Benchmark

I wrote a benchmark (see below). I'll be updating this incrementally until I loose interest :) (*I know my dataset isn't representative. If you upload a file, I'll test it with that*)

1. replacing the separate regexes by the single statically compiled regex, speeds up from 14s to 2.1s (**a 6x speedup**); *this is only with the outermost match replaced*
2. replacing the regex_not/regex_version by precompiled regexes did not make much of a difference with my test set (but I don't have actual matching useragents, so that makes sense)

.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public class Program
{
    private struct Browser
    {
        public int ID;
        public string name;
        public Regex regex_match, regex_not, regex_version;
        public int regex_group;
    }

    private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex("(?i)" 
        + "(?<browserid>(?:firefox/|opera/|chrome/|chrome/|safari/|msie[+_ ]?))"
        + "(?<version>[\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Browser[] browsers = new Browser[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            browsers[i].ID = i;
        }
        browsers[0].name = "Firefox";
        browsers[1].name = "Opera";
        browsers[2].name = "Chrome";
        browsers[3].name = "Safari";
        browsers[4].name = "Internet Explorer";
        browsers[0].regex_match = new Regex("(?i)firefox/([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[1].regex_match = new Regex("(?i)opera/([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[2].regex_match = new Regex("(?i)chrome/([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[3].regex_match = new Regex("(?i)safari/([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[4].regex_match = new Regex("(?i)msie([+_ ]|)([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        // OPTIMIZATION #2
        browsers[0].regex_not = new Regex("(?i)flock", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[1].regex_not = null;
        browsers[2].regex_not = null;
        browsers[3].regex_not = new Regex("(?i)android|arora|chrome|shiira", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[4].regex_not = new Regex("(?i)webtv|omniweb|opera", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        // OPTIMIZATION #2
        browsers[0].regex_version = new Regex("(?i)firefox/([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[1].regex_version = new Regex("(?i)opera/([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[2].regex_version = new Regex("(?i)chrome/([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[3].regex_version = new Regex("(?i)version/([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[4].regex_version = new Regex("(?i)msie([+_ ]|)([\\d\\.]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
        browsers[0].regex_group = 1;
        browsers[1].regex_group = 1;
        browsers[2].regex_group = 1;
        browsers[3].regex_group = 1;
        browsers[4].regex_group = 2;
        Dictionary<string, int> browser_counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        var lookupBrowserId = new Dictionary<string, int> {
            { "firefox/", 0 },
            { "opera/", 1 },
            { "chrome/", 2 },
            { "safari/", 3 },
            { "msie+", 4 },
            { "msie_", 4 },
            { "msie ", 4 },
            { "msie", 4 },
        };

        for (int i=1; i<20; i++)
        foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("/etc/dictionaries-common/words"))
        {
            // OPTIMIZATION #1 START
            Match match = _regex.Match(line);

            {
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    Browser b = browsers[lookupBrowserId[match.Groups["browserid"].Value]];
                    // OPTIMIZATION #1 END

                    // OPTIMIZATION #2
                    if (b.regex_not != null && b.regex_not.IsMatch(line))
                            continue;

                    string strBrowser = b.name;
                    if (b.regex_version != null)
                    {
                        // OPTIMIZATION #2
                        string strVersion = b.regex_version.Match(line).Groups[b.regex_group].Value;
                        int intPeriod = strVersion.IndexOf('.');
                        if (intPeriod > 0)
                        {
                            strBrowser += " " + strVersion.Substring(0, intPeriod);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!browser_counts.ContainsKey(strBrowser))
                    {
                        browser_counts.Add(strBrowser, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        browser_counts[strBrowser]++;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wrote a combined, precompiled regex; make it a static class member. It should be orders of magnitude faster (especially once you avoid matching twice with IsMatch/Matches)

Comment: heh. I fixed a markup fail that apparently happened 2011-09-13 (unless the markdown implementation changed since then...)